# EF6.0 Code First - Change connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

After developing EF codefirst application locally, 
I copied the database from localdb with generate scripts and create a new one at azure.

I added connection string to config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          connectionString="Server=tcp:XXXXXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXXXXX;User ID=XXXXXXXXXXX;Password=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

When I try to call an object, I get this exception:

```
"Invalid object name 'dbo.Banner'."
```

DB connection is correct. I can connect with SQL Server Management Studio.
What is wrong with this code?
Does the manually creating DB cause the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that the tables has not been created.
Some pointers:

Did you enable Automatic Migration?

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
```

You maybe prefer doing a manual update/creation?
In that case, select a project containing the configuration that points to your Azure DB and in the Package Manager console:

> update-database

Or you can do it in code as well using the [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx).

Here are some additional information for reference:
  - [MSDN: Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)
  - [ASP.NET: Code First Migrations and Deployment with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: update-database works thank you. First i cleared all the app.config  but connection string and then migrate db.

Comment: Can the downvoter please enlight me on the reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happen specially when you are restoring database to another server and if you have changed the databse username.

To solve this problem the best way is to change all SCHEMA to dbo.

To change SCHEMA execute following code through your MSSQL Enterpeise manager

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER oldSchema.TableName
```